# exporting csv via phpmyadmin giving out mis-arranged data

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to export a csv file via phpmyadmin,  below are the option I'm selecting,

```
Fields terminated by  ,
Fields enclosed by    "
Fields escaped by     \
Lines terminated by   AUTO
Replace NULL by       NULL
```

Yet when i export the file, if the field contains a comma, the data shifts to the next column cell.

Comment: This issue is not unique to phpMyAdmin. Can you export in another format (ie: tab-delimited)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the rows that gets exported incorrectly?  Or is this a problem with importing somewhere else?

Comment: I'm guessing this has more to do with the file that is importing than the file that is exporting; is this happening with Excel?  Have you tried using OpenOffice.org Calc (since it has a semi-interactive CSV import dialog) to open the file, and then export it to another format?

Comment: If it Excel that you're attempting to import into, set `Fields escaped by character "`

Comment: you all are right, it was all about how the .csv file scans and displays the data, cuz when i opened up that file as a tab delimited, and as .xlsx..... it showed me the data in a proper format..   but I would still like to know.... how can we make the file show in a proper format with csv..... if anyone knows..

Comment: In formal CSV the escape character, as well as the field terminator, is a `"`.  If you set the `Fields escaped by` setting to `"` it should parse correctly.